# TypeScript: Make function argument conditionally optional

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to have function that's take second argument only when some conditions are met.

```js
let fn  = <T extends boolean>(arg1: T, arg2: T extends true ? void : string) => {};

fn(true); // ERROR Expected 2 arguments, but got 1
fn(true, undefined); // OK
fn(false, ''); // OK
```

It's weird behaviour, especially because type function argument as void doesn't force to pass in in a call. Eg:

```js
let fn1 = (arg: void) => {};
fn1(); // OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAZgdhEF4IB4AqEQA8whgEwGcIAjAe1NAEMYA%20ACkoCcBzALglQBoInmBGduiw58RMIwCuICAH4IAN1IBLPBHYFxSmMwCUiGhADeAXwDcAKHOw64qTtMQA9I4gBRAEruA8u6swbkiDcEvggUFogePZOLl4A0n50UJTABEEQAOQZ9pagkLB8iBAMLOyKKnoIBiYWBXTRzhDxQA)

Comment: What is the condition? You *could* have multiple signatures one for `fn(arg1: true)` and one for `fn(arg1: false, arg2: any)` for example. So, the signatures could work. But if the conditions require logic, it might be out of bounds of TS, e.g., if you require `f(a, b)` to only be callable with `a + b < 42`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a design limitation, see [microsoft/TypeScript#29131](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29131).  Treating a trailing `void` function parameter was treated as optional was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#27522](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27522), but the checking for that is shallow and it doesn't work in your conditional type.

I think you might be better off using [tuples in rest parameter positions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-fparameters-with-tuple-types) to get the behavior you want, since tuples can have [optional elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) and even [parameter name labels](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements).   Maybe something like this:

```
let fn = <T extends boolean>(
    arg1: T,
    ...rest: (T extends true ? [arg2?: undefined] : [arg2: string])
) => { };

fn(true); // okay
fn(true, undefined); // okay
fn(true, ''); // error
fn(false); // error
fn(false, undefined); // error
fn(false, ''); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAZgdhC8EA8AVCIAeYQwCYGcIAjAexNAEMYA+ACgCgImIKAnAcwEYAuCFAGkbMAdKNYh8YXrTSZseQmFYBXEBAD8EANpt2AJnW9leEFACWMELgC6EXjo57ek1hfbWAlPQ8JqEAN4QAL4A3PT0sLRKqh4hEAD08RAkANYUAJ4RMFEqIPwQxrimFlaxCUmpGVk5qvkA5HVlieisrCSs1VAUwPggTUkgre0Qnd29+YXFlrj9LW0dkV09eRANs5WZQA)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot :)